# Aplicar a propriedade de CSS "content" sem recorrer à folha de estilos

Tags: css

Tenho um web-site que está disponível em diversas línguas, e para não ter que refazer toda a estrutura de um slider de imagens, existe um pequeno texto que no momento está a ser aplicado através do seletor [**`:before`**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/%3abefore) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> fazendo uso da propriedade [**`content`**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/content) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

[**Exemplo no JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/MdWAH/)

**HTML**

```html
<ul>
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS** *relevante*

```css
ul{
    display:block;
    margin:40px;
    position:relative;
}
ul:before{
    content: "imagens adicionais:";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:-26px;
    color:#7F8C8C;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

## Problema

A solução actualmente em uso requer que o texto esteja na folha de estilos do web-site, o que inviabiliza (de certa forma) a sua tradução!

## Pergunta

Como posso aplicar a propriedade `content` ao seletor `:before` sem recorrer à  folha de estilos?

<sup>Fazendo uso do atributo `style` ou recorrendo a JavaScript como último recurso!</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use content:attr(atributo), segue um exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<div data-text='texto que será impresso no after'> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div:after {
content:attr(data-text);
}
```

Comment: Importante ressaltar que essa tecnica nao funciona em IE<8, caso voce ainda precise dar suporte. Nesse caso adicione um elemento e defina o show/hide com a classe `ie7` na sua tag HTML condicional.

Comment: @JoãoCunha, não achei que valia a pena comentar já que pseudo elementos :after e :before, que ele já usa hoje, só são suportados a partir da versão 8 do IE.